# Any way to save peeling faux-leather boots?

Tags: leather

I have some great fake leather boots that work well in every way except that the fake leather is now peeling off of them rather dramatically.

I was wondering, is there a way to save them? Shoe polish didn't work, and I'm thinking if I paint them they'll just peel off with the paint.

I feel like this is probably a common problem, and it seems a real shame to toss them in a landfill.

Comment: Fake leather is usually done once it starts to delaminate, but there may be other ways to fix it. Do you any photos of the issue?